# Azure Search. How to get result counts when having pagination

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

Lets say I have following schema in Azure Search Collection, with 100s of records.

```
{
"id": '1',
"Status" : "Available",
"name" : "demo 1"
},
{
"id": '2',
"Status" : "Available",
"name" : "demo 1"
},
{
"id": '3',
"Status" : "Removed",
"name" : "demo 1"
},
{
"id": '4',
"Status" : "Booked",
"name" : "demo 4"
}
```

In My Status field I can have three different values,
"Booked", "Available", "Removed".

Now I am getting the data by pagination using Skip and Top from the Azure Search.

However like in ElasticSearch Aggregation function, is there a way in Azure search to get total no of sites having status Booked , Available or not removed etc..
Because I cant do a count in Client Side because, I will have limited no of records, not all records from Azure Search.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would want to see aggregates and records in a single query result. Correct? Or would issuing 2 separate queries (one for pagination data & other for aggregates) an option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a search index client object (**Microsoft.Azure.Search.SearchIndexClient**) to search for your documents you can provide an object as a parameter (**Microsoft.Azure.Search.Models.SearchParameters**) that contains a property `IncludeTotalResultCount`. Once you set this property to true and call the method `Documents.Search(...)` passing the parameter object, your response object (**Microsoft.Azure.Search.DocumentSearchResult**) will contain a value for the property Count considering the total count for the filter, regardless how many items selected by the pagination.

```
SearchParameters searchParameter = new SearchParameters
    {
        Filter = "organizationId eq '1'",
        Skip = 0,
        Top = 20,
        IncludeTotalResultCount = true
     };
     using (var client = new SearchIndexClient(...)
     {
        DocumentSearchResult response = client.Documents.Search("*", searchParameter);

        //pagination items
        var collection = response.Results.ToArray();

        //total items
        var counter = response.Count;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create the index, make the `status` field `facetable` and `filterable`. Then issue a facets query on status, with `$filter=status ne 'Booked'`. This will give you the total counts of documents in each status category other than Booked, irrespective of pagination.

Comment: Thanks I did end up doing facetable